# android:how to set text view as bold by coding not via XML

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to set text of `TextView` as **Bold** style from code instead of XML?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

for textview set bold by coding

using this..

```
TextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

And:

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
```